# Can we pin some post with best reliable links for online Hindu scriptures

Tags: feature-request

I have seen many sites containing various versions of the same Hindu Vedas, Puranas or other texts. But some of them might be reliable and some might not be too good. If readers try to find the source they might start up with a non reliable one and understand things differently. So, can we make a question or some page containing links for all Vedas, Puranas, Epics, etc from best reliable sources, eg SacredText, etc and pin that question such that it always appear on top of the question list. Pinning will enable all users to have easy access to the same.

Also, if all links are not available currently we can atleast start this and keep on adding links as and when we find.

Comment: There is no need to pin as such, only thing you have to do is create a question on meta, answer it canonically and I will make the post community wiki so that everyone can contribute.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know about Community wiki. Can you please explain what it is. And would it be readily available for all people or will they have to search like searching for a question. If they have to search then it will defeat the purpose as user might not search and straight away go to an unreliable reference.

Comment: [All you need to know about community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)